# Applying function to a single newly created element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I could use `each` to iterate over a set of matched selectors, and apply some functionality such as displaying prompt text in an input.

```
$('.default-value').each(function () {
    var $t = $(this),
    default_value = this.value;
    $t.css('color', '#929292');
    $t.focus(function () {
        if (this.value == default_value) {
            this.value = '';
            $t.css('color', 'black');
        }
    });
    $t.blur(function () {
        if ($.trim(this.value) == '') {
            $t.css('color', '#929292');
            this.value = default_value;
        }
    });
});
```

Instead, I wish to write some JavaScript which takes an array, creates some inputs, and applies the same functionality as above to it.  For instance, in the below script, I need to add the functionality to the newly created `input` elements, and would rather not use `each` to iterate over them.  How can this be accomplished?

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    dialog_prompt: function(obj) {

        var dialog=$('div')
        .append($('input',{type: 'hidden',autofocus: 'autofocus'}));

        var arrayLength = obj.elements.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
            var input=$('input',obj.elements[i].update?{'class': 'update-value'}:{});
             //How do I add the .default-value script to this element?
            dialog.append(input);
        }
        //Other script goes here...
        return this.each(function () {
            $(this).dialog(obj);
        });
    }
});
```

EDIT

Would it be something like the following?  Where do I save `default_value`?

```
var input=$('input',obj.elements[i].update?{'class': 'update-value'}:{})
.css('color', '#929292')
.focus(function () {
    if (this.value == default_value) { //Where is default_value now applied
        this.value = '';
        $t.css('color', 'black');
    }
})
.blur(function () {
    if ($.trim(this.value) == '') {
        $t.css('color', '#929292');
        this.value = default_value; //Where is default_value now applied
    }
})
```

Comment: What is the point of not using `.each()`?  You can use a plain `for` loop or a `while` loop or `.forEach()` on the array itself if you so choose - their are plenty of ways to iterate an array.  Please describe your actual objective here.

Comment: @jfriend00  I am not against using `.each()`.  Would I append all the inputs to `dialog`, and then use `.each()` or `.find('input')`, and do similarly to the first example?

Comment: I do not understand what that comment means or what your question means.  You will have to clarify further.

Comment: @jfriend00  Sorry for the confusion.  When I use `.each()`, it appears to create it's own namespace each time as variables like `default_value` each are unique and keep their own values.  I don't blame you for being confused, because I am sure I am not making sense.  Better give this more thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comments, it appears you're asking about how to handle variables inside a `.each()` callback.  If you declare a variable with `var` inside the `.each()` callback function, it will only exist for the lifetime of that specific callback and a new variable will be created each time the callback function is called.  It's just a normal local variable in a function.  It is created and destroyed each time the function is called:

```
xxx.each(function() {
    var temporaryVariable;    // survives only for the duration of the function call
});
```

If you want a variable to last across all `.each()` callback calls, then declare it at a higher scope so it exists across all the callback calls.

```
var longerPeristingVariable = [];
xxx.each(function() {
    longerPersistingVariable.push("whatever");
});
console.log(longerPeristingVariable);
```

Comment: Thanks jfriend00.  I think that makes sense.  Back to my initial example, `each()` is applied when the DOM loads.  But then after the page, `blur` and `focus` still have access to that variable.  Can you help clarify what is happening?  Thanks

Comment: @user1032531 - sorry, but I don't understand what else you're asking.

Comment: the blur callback still has access to the initial `default_value` variable???  `$('.default-value').each(function () { var $t = $(this), default_value = this.value; $t.focus(function () {console.log(default_value)});});`

Comment: Or in otherwords, is this how it is done?  It just doesn't seem right. `$('input').each(function () {var $t = $(this),default_value = this.value;$t.focus(function () {bla bla bla});});`

Comment: @user1032531 - `default_value` is declared in a higher scope.  It is available to any code that is declared within its same scope or in any lower scope (just like longerPersistingVaraible` in my code example is available to the `.each()` callback function).  So, yes `default_value` is available to the blur event handler because that event handler is declared within the same scope and thus has access to everything within that scope.

Answer (score 2):

Example of binding and using data elements for defaults.
http://jsfiddle.net/yt92sL2f/

Updated version abstracts the color to a css class and also fixes a logic error if the user actually types in the default value which was causing the color to not go back to the grayish color.
http://jsfiddle.net/yt92sL2f/11/

```
var $inputs = $('.default-value');

$inputs
    .on('focus', function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        if ($this.val() === $this.data('default')) {
            $this.val('');
            $this.removeClass('default');
        }
    })
    .on('blur', function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        if ($this.val().length < 1) {
            $this.val($this.data('default'));
        }

        if ($this.val() === $this.data('default')) {
            $this.addClass('default');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the jquery "on" method to apply an event to all inputs in the dialog. An example would be:

```
$('#dialog').on('click', 'input', function () { alert("testing"); });
```

You can find the documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Thanks Sam.  I think you are on to something.  I edited my original post to add the use of `on()`.  Please take a look.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For this

```
var input=$('input',obj.elements[i].update?{'class': 'update-value'}:{});
             //How do I add the .default-value script to this element?
```

Try this

```
var input = $('<input/>')
                 .addClass(obj.elements[i].update ? 'update-value':'')
                 .val(/*yer value here*/)
                 .appendTo(dialog);
```